# SonicWall SSL VPN Log Export

Tags: vpn, ssl, log-files, logging

I would like to automatically pull the log file out of my SonicWall SSL VPN. If I login to the interface, I am able to click an export button and download a file I can process; however, I cannot find any way to automatically download this file.

I've tried using Fiddler to track down where it comes from, but with no luck.

I would be OK with the SonicWall dropping the file on a file server or having my process utility download it from the SonicWall.

I see options for Syslog server [not exactly sure how that works] and for emailing the log file, neither of these options fits what I want to do very well. But if you could shed some light on syslog servers that may get me going down the right path.

My end goal is to read this log file and stuff it into my own database.

Any help on this issue is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fuzzered, really syslog is your best option. All firewalls should be syslogged. Check out [Kiwi Syslog](http://www.kiwisyslog.com/kiwi-syslog-server-overview/). Use the free version and you will have all of the logged data you need. You can even change the format it is in. Just download it to any server or desktop and point your sonicwall to it.

Comment: How does Kiwi store it's data? My objective is to get the data from multiple logs (on devievs that support syslog and some that don't) into my own database in my own tables. Is that posible with Kiwi?

Comment: Syslog saves into a plain text .log file. I suppose you could easily import that inot a database if needed. You may also want to take a look at splunk as well.